# Kibana - different time range within dashboard

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have discovered Kibana last week, I find this tool very useful but.. I can't help but wonder how can I bypass Kibana's limitation to one time range for whole dashboard (https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3578)?

I need to present data for different time ranges on one page. It will include pie charts, data tables etc..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that without changing Kibana's code to create a solution of your own.
Here is the github issue tracking the request:

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3578